# Problem with gatsby: command not found when deploying gatsby site to netlify

Tags: reactjs, deployment, web-deployment, gatsby, netlify

I was trying to deploy gatsby site to Netlify. I commit all files from `public` directory within gatsby project to my github repository and then deploy that repository on netlify, but I got an error.

After pushing to github all files and directories except for `public` and then deploy I got following error:

```
12:23:37 PM: ​
12:23:37 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
12:23:37 PM: │        Netlify Build        │
12:23:37 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
12:23:37 PM: ​
12:23:37 PM: ❯ Version
12:23:37 PM:   @netlify/build 3.3.0
12:23:37 PM: ​
12:23:37 PM: ❯ Flags
12:23:37 PM:   deployId: 5f4637d3e090c2ab4a26309c
12:23:37 PM:   mode: buildbot
12:23:37 PM: ​
12:23:37 PM: ❯ Current directory
12:23:37 PM:   /opt/build/repo
12:23:37 PM: ​
12:23:37 PM: ❯ Config file
12:23:37 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
12:23:37 PM: ​
12:23:37 PM: ❯ Context
12:23:37 PM:   production
12:23:37 PM: ​
12:23:37 PM: ┌───────────────────────────────────┐
12:23:37 PM: │ 1. Build command from Netlify app │
12:23:37 PM: └───────────────────────────────────┘
12:23:37 PM: ​
12:23:37 PM: $ gatsby build
12:23:40 PM: success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.022s
12:23:40 PM: success load plugins - 0.498s
12:23:40 PM: success onPreInit - 0.040s
12:23:40 PM: success delete html and css files from previous builds - 0.002s
12:23:40 PM: success initialize cache - 0.006s
12:23:41 PM: success copy gatsby files - 0.028s
12:23:41 PM: success onPreBootstrap - 0.005s
12:23:41 PM: success createSchemaCustomization - 0.006s
12:23:41 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
12:23:41 PM: success source and transform nodes - 0.086s
12:23:41 PM: success building schema - 0.271s
12:23:41 PM: success createPages - 0.001s
12:23:41 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
12:23:41 PM: success createPagesStatefully - 0.067s
12:23:41 PM: success update schema - 0.023s
12:23:41 PM: success onPreExtractQueries - 0.001s
12:23:43 PM: success extract queries from components - 2.444s
12:23:43 PM: success write out redirect data - 0.001s
12:23:43 PM: success onPostBootstrap - 0.000s
12:23:43 PM: info bootstrap finished - 6.517s
12:23:44 PM: success run static queries - 0.017s - 1/1 60.34/s
12:23:44 PM: success run page queries - 0.004s - 1/1 241.80/s
12:23:44 PM: success write out requires - 0.004s
12:24:11 PM: success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 27.400s
12:24:11 PM: success Rewriting compilation hashes - 0.002s
12:24:15 PM: failed Building static HTML for pages - 3.641s
12:24:15 PM: error "document" is not available during server side rendering.
12:24:15 PM: 
12:24:15 PM: > 1 | !function(e,t){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=t():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define([],t):"object"==typeof exports?exports.AOS=t():e.AOS=t()}(this,function(){return function(e){function t(o){if(n[o])return n[o].exports;var i=n[o]={exports:{},id:o,loaded:!1};return e[o].call(i.exports,i,i.exports,t),i.loaded=!0,i.exports}var n={};return t.m=e,t.c=n,t.p="dist/",t(0)}([function(e,t,n){"use strict";function o(e){return e&&e.__esModule?e:{default:e}}var i=Object.assign||function(e){for(var t=1;t<arguments.length;t++){var n=arguments[t];for(var o in n)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,o)&&(e[o]=n[o])}return e},r=n(1),a=(o(r),n(6)),u=o(a),c=n(7),s=o(c),f=n(8),d=o(f),l=n(9),p=o(l),m=n(10),b=o(m),v=n(11),y=o(v),g=n(14),h=o(g),w=[],k=!1,x={offset:120,delay:0,easing:"ease",duration:400,disable:!1,once:!1,startEvent:"DOMContentLoaded",throttleDelay:99,debounceDelay:50,disableMutationObserver:!1},j=function(){var e=arguments.length>0&&void
12:24:15 PM:     |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ^
12:24:15 PM: 
12:24:15 PM:   WebpackError: ReferenceError: document is not defined
12:24:15 PM:   
12:24:15 PM:   - aos.js:1 
12:24:15 PM:     node_modules/aos/dist/aos.js:1:14565
12:24:15 PM:   
12:24:15 PM:   - aos.js:1 
12:24:15 PM:     node_modules/aos/dist/aos.js:1:1506
12:24:15 PM:   
12:24:15 PM:   - Technologie.js:8 
12:24:15 PM:     src/components/Technologie.js:8:5
12:24:15 PM:   
12:24:15 PM:   - index.js:1 
12:24:15 PM:     src/pages/index.js:1:1
12:24:15 PM:   
12:24:15 PM:   - getLayoutRect.js:1 
12:24:15 PM:     node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getLayoutRect.js:1:1
12:24:15 PM:   
12:24:15 PM: 
12:24:15 PM: ​
12:24:15 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
12:24:15 PM: │   "build.command" failed    │
12:24:15 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
12:24:15 PM: ​
12:24:15 PM:   Error message
12:24:15 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: gatsby build
12:24:15 PM: ​
12:24:15 PM:   Error location
12:24:15 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
12:24:15 PM:   gatsby build
12:24:15 PM: ​
12:24:15 PM:   Resolved config
12:24:15 PM:   build:
12:24:15 PM:     command: gatsby build
12:24:15 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
12:24:15 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/public
12:24:15 PM: Caching artifacts
12:24:15 PM: Started saving node modules
12:24:15 PM: Finished saving node modules
12:24:15 PM: Started saving build plugins
12:24:15 PM: Finished saving build plugins
12:24:15 PM: Started saving pip cache
12:24:15 PM: Finished saving pip cache
12:24:15 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
12:24:15 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
12:24:15 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
12:24:15 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
12:24:15 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
12:24:15 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
12:24:15 PM: Started saving go dependencies
12:24:15 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
12:24:18 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
12:24:18 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
12:24:18 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
12:24:19 PM: Finished processing build request in 2m5.540557721s
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you committed the files in `public`, and the error suggests you don't have `gatsby` in your package.json. Are you trying to avoid using Netlify builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a process misunderstanding there. In your repository, you should commit all files except your `/public` folder since it's the one that will be generated in the building and deploy process in Netlify. In addition, your `netlify.toml` is not adding any useful command to Netlify because they are added by default in the dashboard. As you can see in:

[image]

*Note: you can find this configuration under https://app.netlify.com/sites/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/settings/deploys*

Your command is failing because you are doing the Netlify work in your repository. You are uploading a built folder (`/public`) that doesn't contain any `package.json` nor build commands so your command is unrecognized.

You must upload all files except your `/public` folder in your repository and let Netlify do the build process. In addition, you can improve your `netlify.toml` by removing the default commands.

With the new edited content it's inferred that
this build must fail locally too before pushing it to Netlify. In Gatsby, you have to check for the availability of the global objects (like `window` or `document` before using it).

It's a broad question and spreads the topic of it. If the error is in your code (you are using `document` object) you need to add a condition first:

```
If (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  //Your code here
}
```

If the error comes from an external source (library or dependency using `window` or `document` internally), you need to add a null loader in your webpack's configuration:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /bad-module/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Replacing `/bad-module/` for the library path in `node_modules`.

You can check for further details in [Debugging HTML Builds Documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/)

To add properly AOS package add this to your page/component:

```
componentDidMount() { 
const AOS = require('aos'); 
this.aos = AOS this.aos.init() 
} 
componentDidUpdate() { 
this.aos.refresh() 
}
```

Or using hooks:

```
let AOS; 
useEffect(() => { 

/** * Server-side rendering does not provide the 'document' object 
* therefore this import is required either in useEffect or componentDidMount as they 
* are exclusively executed on a client */ 

const AOS = require("aos"); 
AOS.init({ once: true, }); }, []); 

useEffect(() => { if (AOS) { AOS.refresh(); } });
```

Comment: This build must fail locally too without pushing it to Netlify. In Gatsby, you have to check for the availability of the global objects (like `window` or `document` before using it). I've updated the answer but you may need to debug and check https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/

Comment: The problem is `AOS` library, but neither `/node_modules/aos`, nor `/aos` or `/aos/dist/aos.js/` in place of `/bad module/` works.

Comment: Did you try `/aos/`? It's a regular expression.

Comment: `/aos/dist/` may work. Anyway, the error rely in that package. Check https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569360/gatsbyjs-reactjs-aosanimate-on-scroll-causing-build-problems&ved=2ahUKEwjT3cm997jrAhWRlxQKHQLXDTwQjjgwC3oECAwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0vadq87qc_f1dsRw50EdK8

Comment: Doesn't work, but fix it using another library for animations on scroll. Thanks for your help!